# Deleting the treeMap entries with null values

Tags: java, dictionary, treemap

I am attempting to remove all the nulls, but if the last key's treeSet is null then it remains there. So I was thinking how to delete the last entry if it is null. Since this is a treeMap I thought that I can obtain the last element by accessing it with tm.lastKey() but that method does not seem to exist. So this question is twofold. First, is there a way to delete all the nulls including the last one and the second is, where is the .lastKey() method?

```
public class Timing {
    private static Map<String, SortedSet> tm = new TreeMap<String, SortedSet>();

    public static Map manipulate() {
        SortedSet ss = new TreeSet();
        ss.add("APPL");
        ss.add("VOD");
        ss.add("MSFT");

        tm.put("2019-09-18",null);
        tm.put("2019-09-21",ss);
        tm.put("2019-09-22", null);
        tm.put("2019-09-20",ss);
        tm.put("2019-09-19", null);
        tm.put("2019-09-23",null);

        return tm;
    }

    public static void printMap() {
        for (String s: tm.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(s + ": " + tm.get(s));
        }
    }

    // Will delete all but the last one
    public static void deleteNull() {
        Set set = tm.entrySet();
        Iterator i = set.iterator();
        Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry) i.next();
        // there is no tm.lastKey()??
        while(i.hasNext()) {
            if (me.getValue() == null) {
                i.remove();
            }
            me = (Map.Entry) i.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use raw types.

Comment: Your `tm` is a `Map<>`. Naturally methods of `TreeMap` won't be visible on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To remove all entries with a value of `null` from your map you can replace the `deleteNull` method with

```
tm.values().removeIf(Objects::isNull);
```

Comment: very elegant indeed

Answer (score 0):

A Java `TreeMap` does specify a `lastKey()` method. You can see it in the [Java-Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#lastKey()) for `TreeMap`.

The problem is, you can not access the method because you are hiding the real type of your map to your method. You can see it here:

```
private static Map<String, SortedSet> tm = new TreeMap<String, SortedSet>();
```

From this, your method only knows that `tm` is a `Map` object and those do not have the `lastKey()` method. Change `Map` to `TreeMap` or do a cast inside your method, then it will work.

Alternative 1:

```
private static TreeMap<String, SortedSet> tm = new TreeMap<String, SortedSet>();
```

Alternative 2:

```
public String lastKey() {
    if (tm instanceof TreeMap<?, ?>) {
        return ((TreeMap<String, SortedSet>) tm).lastKey();
    } else {
        // Error!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The absolute simplest way to do this would be to run check the iterator one more time after the while loop ends, like so:

```
while(i.hasNext()) {
    if (me.getValue() == null) {
        i.remove();
    }
    me = (Map.Entry) i.next();
}
if (me.getValue() == null) {
    i.remove();
}
    me = (Map.Entry) i.next();
```

This way you'll catch the last value.

However, you can use the key set similar to how you printed the the map.

```
Set<String> keySet = tm.keySet();
for(int ndx = 0; ndx < keySet.size(); ndx++){
    String key = keySet.get(ndx);
    if(tm.get(key) == null){
        tm.remove(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't the size of the set change after some entries were removed? and so we would either get the multhithread exception or indexout of bounds?

Comment: good try but the absolute simplest way is Modus's answer in my opinion :)